# RMStore crashes on (with iAP Crazy) jailbroken iphone

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, rmstore

I am testing my app's inapp purchase  on a jailbroken iphone so that users wont be able to crack its iap using iAP Crazy, iAP cracker etc. problem is it crashes when app is not on debug mode (works fine when debugging via xcode (with iapcrazy, iap cracker installed), also works fine when (debugging or not debugging, when iAPCrazy and iap cracker not installed)

hope someone can help me.

I am using RMStore https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore for purchasing

here is my code

```
 repeatValidator = 0;

    [[RMStore defaultStore] addPayment:item_id success:^(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction) {

        const BOOL verified = [self verifyReceiptWithCustomLogic];
        if (verified)
        {
            [HUD hide:YES];
            [db pushToLog:1 withPuchaseType:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PAYMENT SUCCESSFULLY RECEIVED ON %@",item_id]];

            if (repeatValidator == 0){
                [self goAdd];
                repeatValidator = 1;
            }
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            [HUD hide:YES];
            NSLog(@"Product purchased verified");
        }
        else
        { // Apple recommends to refresh the receipt if validation fails on iOS
            [[RMStore defaultStore] refreshReceiptOnSuccess:^{
                const BOOL verified = [self verifyReceiptWithCustomLogic];
                if (verified)
                {
                   [HUD hide:YES];
                    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                    NSLog(@"Product purchased verified (2)");
                    if (repeatValidator == 0){
                        [self goAdd];
                        repeatValidator = 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    UIAlertView *myAlert3 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Transaction cannot proceed. \nServer cannot verify payment" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                    [myAlert3 show];

                   // [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                    [db pushToLog:1 withPuchaseType:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MALICIOUS TRANSACTION ON %@",item_id]];
                    [HUD hide:YES];
                    [self enableButtons];
                    NSLog(@"V FAILED REF (1)");


                }
            } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                [db pushToLog:1 withPuchaseType:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MALICIOUS TRANSACTION OR BAD COONECTION AT %@",item_id]];
                NSLog(@"V FAILED REF (2)");
                [self enableButtons];
                [HUD hide:YES];
            }];
        }

    } failure:^(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction, NSError *error) {
        //[self failedTransaction:transaction];
        [db pushToLog:1 withPuchaseType:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TRANSACTION DISMISSED ON %@",item_id]];
        [HUD hide:YES];
        [self enableButtons];
        NSLog(@"V FAILED REF (3)");
    }];
```

Comment: Crashing on a jailbroken phone with a cracker installed sounds like a reasonable behaviour to me.